# Password expired on ssh

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, buildroot

I booted my Raspberry Pi with a buildroot image I generated myself, and now I am trying to connect to raspberry via ssh.

Everything seems to be fine and the raspberry gets connected. But when I try to log in with root it says access denied. So I created a new user, but when I try to login with that user it says that my password expired and that I have to change it.

I went to my shadow file on my rpi and I got this:

```
nada:blabla/blabla/blabla/:0:0:99999:7:0:0
```

This technically means that password would expire 273 years from now.

I thought the problem was that my rpi date is Jan 1970, but I don't understand since expiration is maximised. Do you have any idea on what might be causing this?

Comment: You cannot login with root remotely. As for the password, are you not sure it is just expired the first time you login, for forcing you to change it?

Comment: check your `/etc/shadow` file (esp. if you edited it yourself) - I count one too few fields ( the ':' character is the delimiter )

Comment: i tried changing the passwords but connection shuts down right after and nothing changes on my rpi password stays the same.
for the /etc/shadow i already mentioned what i had in it for my user nada so i dont know what i have to edit or not cause i guess it is already set to max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's what i've done :

i changed date on my rpi using the date command and then changed my password again. it worked fine thought when i tried this the first time a few days ago it didn't work i must've spelled something wrong or something.
here are the commands :

`date -s 1801090852`
 for "jan 09 2018 at 08:52" there are other formats i was first working with a raspberry pi model B+ (that's broken right now) and the format was 0109085318 so check for the correct syntax.

`passwd user` 
to change your user's password.

thank you to those who answered.